# PHP Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0

Tags: php

I'm getting this in my php-error log, im not sure where $pad is being set:

> PHP Warning:  str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or
>   equal to 0 in file.php on line 105

Here is the code:

```
    $tokens = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $xml)));

    $result     = ''; // holds formatted version as it is built
    $pad        = 0; // initial indent
    $matches    = array(); // returns from preg_matches()

    $insideCDATA = false;
    $currentCDATA = null;

    foreach($tokens as $token) {
        $closeCDATA = false;

        if (preg_match('/^<!\[CDATA.*\]\]>$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $indent = 0;
        elseif (preg_match('/^<!\[CDATA.*$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $insideCDATA = true;
            $currentCDATA = '';
        elseif (preg_match('/.+\]\]>$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $insideCDATA = false;
            $closeCDATA = true;
            $indent = 0;
        elseif (preg_match('/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/', $token, $matches)) : 
            $indent = 0;
        elseif (preg_match('/^<\/\w/', $token, $matches)) :
            if (!$insideCDATA) {
                $pad--;
            }
            $indent = 0;
        elseif (preg_match('/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $indent = 1;
        else :
            $indent = 0; 
        endif;

        if ($insideCDATA) {
            $currentCDATA .= $token;
        } else {
            if ($closeCDATA) {
                $token = $currentCDATA.$token;
                $currentCDATA = null;
            }
            $line    = str_repeat("\t", $pad).$token;
            $result .= $line . "\n"; // add to the cumulative result, with linefeed
            $pad    += $indent; // update the pad size for subsequent lines    
        }
    }

    return $result;
```

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `$pad`? Presumably, wherever it's being set, it's not being set properly

Comment: Do `var_dump($pad);` and see what's in there

Comment: Not quite sure where it's being set

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your code more stable, checking parameters prior to passing it to function. In your case you initialize `$pad` with zero, but then you can decrement this value and your second param to str_repeat can be less then zero.

For example, in this case you can call `str_repeat` in this manner `str_repeat( "\t", ($pad >=0) ? $pad : 0 )`

```
if ($insideCDATA) {
    $currentCDATA .= $token;
} else {
    if ($closeCDATA) {
        $token = $currentCDATA.$token;
        $currentCDATA = null;
    }
    $line    = str_repeat( "\t", ($pad >=0) ? $pad : 0 ).$token;
    $result .= $line . "\n"; // add to the cumulative result, with linefeed
    $pad    += $indent; // update the pad size for subsequent lines
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you think this change would fix this problem?

Comment: This solution will remove Warning, but maybe there are error in your code and that's why your $pad isn't defined before call `str_repeat`

Comment: I've changed code to remove any following warning, notices for not defined variable $pad

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea how i can find where the $pad is beeing used?

Comment: I find problem, your $pad can be less then zero, because you initialize $pad with zero and in some case decrement it. So I've changed answer to fix this exactly this problem

Comment: I got it, thanks. So i should just replace the code with your code?

Comment: just replace your `$line` string with this `$line    = str_repeat( "\t", ($pad >=0) ? $pad : 0 ).$token;`

Comment: Thanks for your help!